# error while redirecting to https

Tags: apache, server, httpd.conf, rhel, mod-ssl

I have configured SSL on my webserver of rhel system. I update ssl.conf file using below cond.  When i use, http:///ServiceRequest, it redirects to https.  However, it display error `The requested URL /ServiceRequest was not found on this server`.  I am using webserver to app server redirection.  Added below logic:
`<VirtualHost _default_:80>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ServiceRequest/

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ServiceRequest [R,L]`

Can someone tell me where i am doing wrong? My purpose is to redirect the request to appserver and when we use http..it should redirect to https.

Comment: Do you have a VirtualHost for the HTTPS?

Comment: Yes...I did maintained as below:  `<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/http/servercert.pem  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/http/apachecert.key  
....
</VirtualHost>`